# How do I add a long press on ios-charts?

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I need to display the X-axis information when I press the bar chart,
I can add marker to bar chart.
But how to add the long press sign to the bar chart?

Comment: [Check this.](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/2656)

Comment: Hi LC_Chan, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  I have no idea whatsoever what you are trying to ask.  Could you please clarify your question, for instance by including some sample code, or a more detailed explanation of what you're working on, what language you're coding in, etc.?  Thanks!

Comment: `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` didn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to add long press gesture on your bar chart

Add LongPressGesture on BarChart :

```
let longPressgesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressDetected(gesture:)))
longPressgesture.allowableMovement = 50
self.barChartView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressgesture)
```

LongPressGesture Handler :

```
@objc func longPressDetected(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

      if gesture.state == .ended {
            let point = gesture.location(in: self.barChartView)
            let h = self.barChartView.getHighlightByTouchPoint(point)
            self.barChartView.highlightValue(x: (h?.x)!, dataSetIndex: (h?.dataSetIndex)!, stackIndex: (h?.stackIndex)!)
        }

}
```

By this you can highlight your bar with longpress.

Hope this will helps!